# Regarding linear probing in hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

> In linear probing hashing, if clustering is not a problem, We will
>   assume a very large table and that each probe is independent of the
>   previous probes. These assumptions are satisfied by a random collision
>   resolution strategy. First, we derive the expected number of probes in
>   an unsuccessful search. This is just the expected number of probes
>   until we find an empty cell. Since the fraction of empty cells is (1 -
>   (N/M)), where N is number of elements and M is hash table size. the
>   number of cells we expect to probe is 1/(1 - (N/M)). The number of
>   probes for a successful search is equal to the number of probes
>   required when the particular element was inserted.

My question is how do we got number of cells we expect to proble is 1/(1-(N/M)) in above text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probing works roughly like this: you have probability p for success, and you keep trying until you succeed.
This means that you're dealing with the [geometric probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), so the expected number of attempts until you succeed is 1/p.

In this case, p=1-(N/M), so the expected number of attempts is 1/(1-(N/M)).